# Google AdMob InterstitialExample not showing ad

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, admob

i got a google Interstitial Example for AdMob from https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/kotlin/admob/InterstitialExample just for test run on my device. But it's not working at all. I'm testing it on the real device and i put real device id in `builder. addTestDevice`, but it's still showing "Ad wasn't loaded." after click. Have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: Post your full code.

Comment: That's absolutely like in that github, but i changed device_id
         val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("F9629AB0617288FDF96BEF70E9154EAD")
                    .build()

Comment: Try checking if the ad was loaded before displaying it. it might have not yet loaded when you are trying to display it.